# Bulk insert in SQL and insert others values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table with 3 fields

```
id_Complex | fileLine | date
```

The field id_Complex, and, that id_complex is the same for the file, that id just chenge when another file is processed is a ID generate from my program, fileLine is just a line from file and date is the date of recording of the line.
Now, my program make a insert in the database for each line read from the file.

I whant to know, if is possible to make a bulk, and that bulk just insert the values in one specific column of table, and, I just send the id_complex to sql, so, the SQL will be make the insert with id_complex I sent for SQL, the lines of file and date.

How I can make that bulk ?
it's possible to make this, Bulk insert with one that has a value predefined

Comment: what do you mean when write "bulk"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should in your program proccess input file and generate temp file with correct complex_id and the make bulk insert for this temp file.

After insert just delete temp file.

Comment: but of course this, and I had not realized, but what about the question of the date and time, is how to generate bulk with the date and time of the system?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you could create a temporary table TempTable and do a bulk insert into it.  Then perform an `UPDATE` from TempTable joining to your permanent table by `id_Complex`.  You can also set the date in this `UPDATE` statement.  Finally, clear out the temporary table.

Alternatively, you could bulk import the file into a temporary table, delete the old permanent table, and rename the temporary table as the permanent table.